# Can I wire a furnace with no control board to run just the fan?

Tags: wiring, furnace

I have an old unit (Coleman 3500A816) that has no control board. It works with a sequencer. Is it possible to wire it up to to be able to call only the blower to come on and not the heat as well?

[image]

Comment: Would a separate external timer switch for the fan do the job?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram for the furnace?

Comment: Done. Also, I have added common wire to the transformer and ran it to my thermostat

Comment: Does the furnace blower motor have a HP rating on its nameplate?

Comment: 1/6 Horsepower rating

Answer (score 3):

### You'll need to add a blower relay to your system

Unfortunately, you have an oddball among electric furnaces in that your furnace controls its blower autonomously using the sequencer relay, much like a gas furnace does with its blower thermostat/limit.  As a result, your electric furnace doesn't support a G wire natively.  Fortunately, it's not too difficult to add one on by splicing a *fan relay* in at the right spot.  In your case, you (or your HVAC tech of choice, if you're not comfortable modding your furnace) need to:

- Get a fan relay with a 24VAC coil and SPDT contacts, as well as appropriately sized female quick connects (1/4" wide, and rated for the gauge of wire in question), and some 18AWG TF(F)N in blue, yellow, and green
- Install the fan relay in the wiring compartment of the furnace
- Move the existing *blue* wire from the sequencer over to the *common* terminal on the fan relay
- Make up a jumper of *blue* TFFN with quick connects on each end and use it to connect the *normally closed* terminal on the fan relay to the sequencer terminal that the original blue wire connected to
- Make up a jumper of *yellow* TFFN and use it to connect the terminal of the sequencer *directly opposite* the blue wire (it has a yellow wire and nothing else connected to it from the factory) to the *normally open* terminal on the fan relay
- Make up another jumper of *blue* TFFN with a quick connect at one end and a stripped end at the other and use it to connect one *coil* terminal on the fan relay to wherever you connected your C wire to
- Crimp a quick connect onto a length of *green* TFFN and strip the other end, then run that from the other *coil* terminal on the fan relay to where the thermostat wires connect; this will become your new G wire, when wirenutted to the incoming G wire from the thermostat

Once you're done hooking everything up, you can turn the system back on and test operation both with the thermostat fan switch in AUTO and the thermostat fan switch in ON, then enjoy your upgraded furnace!